# Android application with server communication

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am new to android i have to send mobile number and pin to the server ,in the server side if both are correct then i have to receive success data from that server, i do not know how please tell me  i tried this but i do not now how to receive server data

```
 my code 

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private EditText value;
private Button btn;
private ProgressBar pb;
private TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.submitBtn);
    pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pb);
    tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    btn.setOnClickListener(this);

  }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(value.getText().toString().length()<1){
        Toast.makeText(this, "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else{
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

}

 private class MyAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{
  protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      postData(params[0]);
      return null;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
      pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Code Sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
  protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
      pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
  }

  public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
      // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/chotu/index.php");
      HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(" http://125.62.200.54/rest/login.php");
      try {

          // Add your data
          List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
          httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

          // Execute HTTP Post Request
          HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

      } 
      catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
      {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      } catch (IOException e)
      {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      }
   }
```

Comment: Have you debugged that `HttpResponse response` doesn't contain any response? Do you have internet permission in the manifest?

Comment: ya i have internet permission in the manifest file

Comment: follow [this](http://osamashabrez.com/simple-client-server-communication-in-android/) tutorial

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader bufferreader;
String line;

public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
      // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
      HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      //HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://"your domen"/chotu/index.php");
      HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(" http://"your domen"/rest/login.php");
      try {

          // Add your data
          List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
          httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

          // Execute HTTP Post Request
          HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

      } 
      catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
      {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      } catch (IOException e)
      {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      }
try{
    bufferreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
       while ((line = bufferreader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
      }
    Log.v(tag, (String) String.valueOf(sb.toString()));
        if(sb.equals(null)){
        Log.v("Respone", sb.toString());
        return("notvalid");
    }
    bufferreader.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.v("Respone", sb.toString());

   }
```